# Datanode disks are full because huge files as stdout

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, datanode

we have the follwing hadoop cluster versions , ( DATA-NODE machine are on Linux OS version - 7.2 )

***ambari - 2.6.1
HDP - 2.6.4***

we saw few scenarios that disks on datanode machine became full 100%

and that because the files as - **stdout** are huge size

for example

```
/grid/sdb/hadoop/yarn/log/application_151746342014_5807/container_e37_151003535122014_5807_03_000001/stdout
```

from df -h , we can see

```
df -h /grid/sdb
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdb        1.8T  1.8T  0T   100% /grid/sdb
```

any suggestion how to avoid this situation that stdout are huge and actually this issue cause stopping the HDFS component on the datanode,

second:
since the PATH of stdout is:

```
/var/log/hadoop-yarn/containers/[application id]/[container id]/stdout
```

is it possible to limit the file size?
or do a purging of stdout when file reached the threshold ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the above path looks like your application (Hadoop Job) is writing a lot of data to `stdout` file. This generally happens when the Job writes `data` to `stdout` using `System.out.println` function or similar which is not required but sometimes can be used to debug code.

Please check your application code and make sure that it does not write to `stdout`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: lets say , we want to do some workaround that will search this files and will  move all lines in the files except the last 1000 lines , can we do that ?

Comment: you can write a cron job which tail last 1000 line to another file. but what you want to achieve with last 1000 lines?